# SQL Query to find Mentors and Mentees

Tags: sql

I was a question in an interview and I haven't been able really figure out the answer since. I feel like I'm close to an answer, but lacking the right syntax. The question easy to state and understand:

Imagine you have a table of `name`s and `age`s like so

```
--------------
| name | age |
--------------
| Joe  |  30 |
| Tom  |  27 |
| Mike |  25 |
--------------
```

Write an SQL query that will return a list of `(name, name`) where the first name in the tuple is a mentor and the second, a mentee. A person is a mentor to anyone who that person is older than. So a solution to the example above would return

```
--------------
| name | age |
--------------
| Joe  | Tom |
| Joe  | Mike|
| Tom  | Mike|
--------------
```

Joe is a mentor to everyone because he is the oldest, and Mike is a mentor to no one because he is the youngest.

For my part of it, I'm all but sure this is a nested query where I have to call the same table up again. I know this syntax is wrong, but I feel like the answer is close to something like:

```
SELECT x.name, y.name
FROM names_ages.x, names_ages.y
WHERE x.name >= ALL(y.name)
```

Dying to know what the real answer is though.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want a `join` with inequality:

```
SELECT mentor.name as mentor, mentee.name as mentee
FROM names_ages mentor JOIN
     names_ages mentee
     ON mentor.age > mentee.age;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT mentor.name, mentee.name
FROM names_ages AS mentor, name_ages AS mentee
WHERE mentor.age > mentee.age;
```